# Searching through XML to find a list of items

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

I have an xml doc as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Categories>
  <Category>
    <Name>Fruit</Name>
    <Items>
      <Item>Apple</Item>
      <Item>Banana</Item>
      <Item>Peach</Item>
      <Item>Strawberry</Item>
    </Items>
  </Category>
  <Category>
    <Name>Vegetable</Name>
    <Items>
      <Item>Carrots</Item>
      <Item>Beets</Item>
      <Item>Green Beans</Item>
      <Item>Bell Pepper</Item>
    </Items>
  </Category>
  <Category>
    <Name>Seafood</Name>
    <Items>
      <Item>Crab</Item>
      <Item>Lobster</Item>
      <Item>Shrimp</Item>
      <Item>Oysters</Item>
      <Item>Salmon</Item>
    </Items>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

I would like to be able to search on a term such as Category.Name = Fruit and get back the list of the Fruit Items.

Here is the incomplete code I've started so far:

```
string localPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Foods.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(localPath);
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("Categories");
//Do something here to search the category names and get back the list of items.
```

This is my first attempt at parsing through XML so I'm a bit lost.  Note: the application I am working on uses .Net 2.0

Comment: are you familiar with `XPATH` sounds like that may be what you may need to use in your case

Comment: I am not familiar with XPATH, is it part of .Net 2.0?  I am open to the best solution but was hoping for an example.

Comment: here are `SO` there are actually tons of examples of how to search or iterate an XML File..

Comment: Read here: [MSDN on the `XmlNode.SelectNodes Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx) and try to come up with a solution that revolves around this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to read about XPath as you're limited to .NET 2.0, moreover XPath is very useful to work with XML even in more general context (not limited to .NET platform only).

In this particular case XPath become useful because `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` method accept XPath string as parameter. For example, to get all `<Item>` that corresponds to category name `"Fruit"` :

```
string localPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Foods.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(localPath);
XmlNodeList items = doc.SelectNodes("Categories/Category[Name='Fruit']/Items/Item");
foreach(XmlNode item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

You can see XPath as a path, similar to file path in windows explorer. I'd try to explain only the bit that is different from common path expression in the above sample, particularly this bit :

```
...\Category[Name='Fruit']\...
```

the expression within square-brackets is a filter which say search for `<Category>` node having child node `<Name>` equals `"Fruit"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path.  However, you would need to load the 'Categories' node first, then you can get it's child nodes.

I have added a filter to return only nodes where the name is "Fruit".

```
XmlNode cat = doc.SelectSingleNode("Categories");
var list = cat.SelectNodes("Category").Cast<XmlNode>()
              .Where(c => c.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText == "Fruit");

foreach ( XmlNode item in list )
{
    // process each node here
}
```